# How to determine which classes are easier to predict with a decision tree?

Tags: classification, decision-trees, classifier

So, I'm trying to work with decision trees on Iris dataset. I've noticed by trying out different parameter (max_depth, leaves etc) that some of the classes are easier to predict (most of the trees give the same prediction). How do I justify this, and is there a way to visualize it based on different trees?

Comment: wouldn't it simply depend upon the sufficiency (prevalence) and quality of the data available for individual classes? You can try an EDA on the prevalence and availability of the data for the various classes. Is it something else you are looking for?

Comment: @jdsuryap Iris dataset is quite balanced although I wouldn't say there is sufficient data.

Comment: Especially with decision trees, easiness to predict a class depends on how different the distribution of the independent variables is from the other classes independent variables in the dataset. For ex. if we are trying to predict cars with max speed  greater than 300 MPH - almost all engines might be greater than 2L in volume and its sufficient.  So entropy of the independent variables filtered for a specific class compared to overall data entropy might give a directional idea.